# Finding a user-defined column from collection without grouping

Tags: mongodb, python-2.7, mongodb-query, pymongo, aggregation-framework

How do I find a user-defined column from a collection without putting it in a  group in mongodb query?

I would like to convert the following SQL query to mongo:

```
SELECT 
    brand_name,
    count(`qty/inventory`) AS totalstock,
    count(if(`qty/inventory`=0, `qty/inventory`, NULL)) as outofstock,
    count(if(`qty/inventory`!=0, `qty/inventory`, NULL)) as availablestock,
    DATE_ADD(stock_updated_at, INTERVAL 318 minute) as stock_updated_at 
FROM tbl_kunuzdatafeed_master 
GROUP BY brand_name 
ORDER BY stock_updated_at desc;
```

Can anyone help with converting this to mongo query?

Comment: Yes we can do it but we will not because it not how things work around here. Please consider to visit the help center and learn [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) also, you need to provide a [mcve] which means sample documents with the expected result. For now, I am voting to close your question as *unclear what you are asking*

Comment: hello sir ..
i want to find stock_updated_at column value without putting it on group 
..below my query..
db.raw_category_data.aggregate( [
            {'$sort':{"stock_updated_at":-1}},

            { "$group": { "_id": {"Brand":"$Brand","stock_updated_at":"$stock_updated_at"},
                        "TotalStock": { "$sum": 1 }
                         

                          } }
        ] )